# how to change frame set to uitextfield to uibutton

Tags: ios, uibutton, uitextfield, frame

hi everyone i have struck one module for 24hrs couldn't get any output.Let me tell whats my problem i have one Textfield and one button. imagine that i placing my textfield in first order and i placing button in second order 
but for some change i need to replace the position to textfield to button position and button position to textfield i.e now button should b in first order and textfield should move to second order
can anyone update code for it

my actual textfield frames are : origin = (x=16,y=139) size =(width=288,height=49). Button frames are = (x=16,y=189) size = (width=288,height=47)

my code for changing frameset

```
Textfield = [[UITextField alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(16, 189, 288, 47)];
Button = [[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(16, 139, 288, 49)];
[self.view addSubview:TextField];
[self.view addSubview:Button];
```

Comment: I would recommend you to share your code/screenshots for a better response from SO users.

Comment: Still incomplete code/question. Would you like to replace your textField with a button and vice versa? In that case why can't you update your frames of textField & button objects?

Comment: i dont knw bro how to change position from textfield to uibutton  position

Comment: You can update the frames, once you know the condition you want to change the positions of two objects.

Comment: i expect codes from u how to move my textfield in second order and how to move my button on above textfield

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this Purpose
1) take `UITextfield` frame in one `CGRect`

```
CGRect Tempframe;
Tempframe = Button.frame;
```

2) set buttons frame as textfield frame

```
Button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = YES;
Button.frame = Textfield.frame;
```

3)At last set the Tempframe as your textfeild frame

```
Textfield.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = YES;
Textfield.frame = Tempframe
```

Comment: thanx for ur sample code @Agent but its not working jam getting same view

Comment: bro first of all i using storyboard and used outlets for textfield and button manually is there any way to change the position

Comment: Glad it helped...... :)
Explaination : The previous one was not working as you had autolayout for your controls afterwards we converted it to constraints using "translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints"